# Use of Location tag in authorization

Tags: c#-4.0, webforms, authorization

I have a **web.config** file through which I am trying to provide role based security to my application using **location** tags. I have read many articles and move to the result, that **location** tags provide the access to the limited folders for the authorized users like in my web config I have a folder "**HRpages**" which only allow access to the users who have roles as "**HR**". But I am not clear how I use this in my code file(**Login.aspx.cs**) for authorization.

**NOTE:** Right now **"Login.aspx.cs"** is not redirecting me to the "**WelcomeHR.aspx**" page. Don't know why.

***Web.Config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
          <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="WelcomePage.aspx">

            </forms>
          </authentication>

          <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
          </authorization>

        </system.web>
      <location path="HRpages">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow roles="HR" />
            <deny users="*" />
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>

      <location path="AdminPages">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin" />
            <deny users="*" />
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>
        <system.webServer>
            <defaultDocument>
                <files>
                    <add value="AddTwoNumbers.asmx" />
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
        </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

***Login.aspx.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace WebServiceExample
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text.Trim() == "ABC" && TextBox2.Text.Trim() == "Gupta" && TextBox3.Text == "HR")
            {


                String returnUrl1;
                // the login is successful
                if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == null)
                {
                    returnUrl1 = "HRPages/WelcomeHR.aspx";
                }

                //login not unsuccessful 
                else
                {
                    returnUrl1 = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
                }
                Response.Redirect(returnUrl1);
            }

        }
        }
    }
```

**Any Help????**

Comment: You are mixing authentication and authorization. Have a look at Microsoft's claims-based authorization framework which should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Likely this case isn't true:

```
if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == null)
```

And even if it were, you aren't logging the user in or setting their Role to "HR"... so on a good redirect, they won't have access to the page.

You can log the user in with [FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx).

```
if (TextBox1.Text.Trim() == "ABC" && TextBox2.Text.Trim() == "Gupta" && TextBox3.Text == "HR")
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("ABC", true); //this will login the user as ABC

    String returnUrl1;
    //I don't understand how the logic below determines successful login or not.

    // the login is successful
    if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == null)
    {
        returnUrl1 = "HRPages/WelcomeHR.aspx";
    }
    //login not unsuccessful 
    ...
```

You'll also have to be using [Role Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b241xwt.aspx)... which you don't reference.